# customize column Highchart with icons

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to customize column Highchart with icons on its ends.
also i want them to be floating on the center.

below is my code what i have tried, but i could not combine *spline* and *columnrange* charts together in order to get the icons.

```
$('#ao-DashBoardDateRanger').highcharts({

            chart: {
                type: 'columnrange',
                inverted: true
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false

            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButtons: {
                        enabled: false,

                    }
                },
                enabled: true
            },
            title: {
                text: 'LIST OF PROJECTS'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['May 2016', 'Jun  2016', 'Jul 2016', 'Aug 2016']
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {

                columnrange: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    groupPadding: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        align : "top"
                    }
                }

                }
            ,

            legend : {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Sales',

                data: [
                    [-9.7, 9.4],
                    [-8.7, 6.5],
                    [-3.5, 9.4],
                    [-1.4, 19.9],

                ]
            }]

        });
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use data labels which show the symbol (with `useHTML`)?

Comment: thats a good idea! let me try.

Comment: You can use two series, first the column and second the scatter with customised marker. Example https://jsfiddle.net/hkdxtkcs/

Comment: Great! i think it has given me a lead to achieve my actual scenario! right now my scenario has been changed with multiple icons on the column series.